# nslookup result for google.com

Tags: nslookup, dns-lookup

I am quite new to the networking world! I was tweaking with some networking concepts and I found that we can use DNS for load-balancing by having multiple records in a DNS name server.

So I ran a `nslookup` for `google.com` and I got only one record. However, when I ran the same command for `stackoverflow.com` I got multiple records. I was wondering why this is happening? have I done something wrong?!

Comment: You have not done something wrong; there's just more than one way to load balance.

Comment: google IP varies depending on where are nslookup send from. Compare your google IP with this one bash.ws/nslookup/google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its a completely Extensive subject .

sometimes you cannot watch this through checking by nslookup.

if the domain dns zone hosted by third party like cloudflare and cloudns that will not expose the ip of nodes. then it cannot 
declared with nslookup . and possibly the ip you watch in this way is only the ip of dns server not the ip of load balancing servers.

by the way using the dns records for load balancing is using same records value with different ip address . then traffic will distributed among different servers with same configuration .